# Bootstrap 3 affix

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have been playing with a [preview of Bootstrap 3](http://rnikitin.github.io/bootstrap/docs/), and have had troubles with the "affix pluggin", which allows for fixed-position floating bars.

Please find a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B62Gp/) showing my troubles. Basically, the right-hand side button does float, but the width and offset styling inherited from the grid system seems to disappear when `position: fixed` is applied.

This is my code:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-span-8'>
            <legend>Lorem</legend>
            <div>[Large amounts of text]</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-span-4 well' data-spy='affix' data-offset-top='50'>
            <div class='btn btn-large btn-danger col-span-12'>This is fixed</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong? (I know Bootstrap 3 is still under active development, but I hope someone with have some insight here.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-offset-top='50'` adds the class `affix-top`. This class has no definition in bootstrap.css. After scrolling the page the class `affix` replace the class `affix-top`.  `affix` defines the position fixed. This caused different displays of your affixed div.

Maybe Changing your code to shown below works more as expected. NB in this case The affixed div isn't shown on small screens?!

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='col-span-8'>
            <legend>Lorem</legend>
            <div>[Large amounts of text]</div>
        </div>
        <div class='col-span-4'>
            <div class="well col-span-4" data-spy='affix'>
            <div class='btn btn-large btn-danger col-span-12'>This is fixed</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please provide a fiddle, I could not make your solution work.

Comment: The Bootstrap 3 markup has changed a little since this was posted: New example - http://bootply.com/73866